Misaligned tiles while using CRS.simple in Leaflet
I have problem in my leaflet project with misaligned tiles after adding CRS.simple to my code Console show paths to negative Y values for tiles, which don't exist in local folder. I would appreciate really any insight, advice or help on the matter. I use standard 256x256 tiles, tms for reverse y order.
function setupMap() {
var mapPath;
var minZoom;
var maxZoom;
var defaultZoom;
var centerX;
var centerY;
var southWest;
var northEast;

// Pobranie bieżącej ścieżki URL
const currentPath = window.location.pathname;

// Sprawdzenie ścieżki i ustawienie odpowiednich wartości
if (currentPath.includes('/white_orchard/index.html')) {
    mapPath = '/resources/maps/white_orchard/{z}/{x}/{y}';
    minZoom = 2;
    maxZoom = 5;
    defaultZoom = 3;
    centerX = -65.000; // Środek mapy na podstawie współrzędnych pixelowych
    centerY = -65.000;
    southWest = L.latLng(-85, -180); // Ustawienie granic
    northEast = L.latLng(0, 45);
} else if (currentPath.includes('/velen_novigrad/index.html')) {
    mapPath = '/resources/maps/hos_velen/{z}/{x}/{y}';
    minZoom = 1;
    maxZoom = 6;
    defaultZoom = 2;
    centerX = 126.000; // Środek mapy na podstawie współrzędnych pixelowych
    centerY = 115.000;
    southWest = L.latLng(0, 0); // Ustawienie granic
    northEast = L.latLng(265, 240);
} else {
    console.error('Nieznana ścieżka mapy');
    return;
}

// Użycie CRS.Simple
var map = L.map('mapid', {
    crs: L.CRS.Simple, // CRS.Simple dla płaskiej mapy
    zoomControl: false,
    fullscreenControl: true,
    center: [centerX, centerY],
    zoom: defaultZoom,
    attributionControl: 1,
    zoomSnap: 0.5,
    zoomDelta: 0.5
}); 

// Dodanie kontrolek zoomu
L.control.zoom({
    position: 'bottomright',
    zoomInTitle: 'Przybliż',
    zoomOutTitle: 'Oddal'
}).addTo(map);

// Okienko z koordynatami
map.on('click', function (e) {
    var coords = e.latlng;
    var lat = coords.lat.toFixed(5);
    var lng = coords.lng.toFixed(5);
    console.log('Map clicked at:', lat, lng);
    L.popup()
        .setLatLng(coords)
        .setContent("Koordynaty: " + lat + ", " + lng)
        .openOn(map);
});

// Granice mapy
var bounds = L.LatLngBounds(southWest, northEast);
map.setMaxBounds(bounds);

// Dodanie warstwy kafelków z opcją TMS
L.tileLayer(mapPath + '.jpg', {
    crs: L.CRS.Simple,
    minZoom: minZoom,
    maxZoom: maxZoom,
    //continuousWorld: true,
    tms: true, // Ustawienie odwrotnej numeracji kafelków
    noWrap: true,
    bounds: bounds
}).addTo(map);

L.tileLayer(mapPath + '.png', {
    crs: L.CRS.Simple,
    minZoom: minZoom,
    maxZoom: maxZoom,
    //continuousWorld: true,
    tms: true, // Ustawienie odwrotnej numeracji kafelków
    noWrap: true,
    bounds: bounds
}).addTo(map);

// Obsługa przycisku wyszukiwania koordynatów
document.getElementById('search-button').addEventListener('click', function () {
    const input = document.getElementById('coordinate-input').value;
    const coords = input.split(',').map(coord => parseFloat(coord.trim()));

    if (coords.length === 2 && !isNaN(coords[0]) && !isNaN(coords[1])) {
        const lat = coords[0];
        const lng = coords[1];

        // Przesunięcie mapy na nowe współrzędne
        map.setView([lat, lng], defaultZoom);

        // Wyświetlenie dymka na mapie
        L.popup()
            .setLatLng([lat, lng])
            .setContent("Koordynaty: " + lat + ", " + lng)
            .openOn(map);
    } else {
        alert("Wpisz poprawne współrzędne w formacie 'lat,lng'");
    }
});
}
// Wywołanie funkcji po załadowaniu DOM
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    setupMap();
 });

